# How to programatically add an icon overlay in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

When a user views the detail for a post that contains a video, I'd like to show a 'play' icon overlaying the post thumbnail.

I've tried this but it doesn't compile:

```
    if ([postType isEqualToString:@"video"]) {
        UIImageView *videoIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vicon"]];
        videoIcon.frame = CGRectMake(5, 10, 35, 35);
        [self addSubview:videoIcon]; 
    }
```

and the error given is:

```
No visible @interface declares the selector addSubview
```

Does anyone know how to make this work?

The above code is within my DetailViewController.m. The overall structure is that of a UICollectionView with Master/Detail interfaces.

Comment: I suspect `self` is a view **controller** and not a view...

Comment: Unless "self" is a view, you can't add a subview; I'm guessing self is a controller of some kind?  Please clarify by specifying a) where you're putting this code, and b) information about the view where you'd like to overlay the icon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps

```
[self.view addSubview:videoIcon];
```

if `self` is not a subclass of `UIView` then `addSubview` is unlikely to be defined